# Select a letter randomly without replacement

Tags: probability

Select 3 letters at random, one at a time without replacement, from the word VARIANCE. The discrete random variable X represents the number of times is selected a letter A
a) find the complete probability distribution of X

Comment: Welcome Norma, is this a testbook problem? - What is your actual question? what have you tried? You could tag your question as `self-study` - have a look at [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to see what it means :-)